# How the user can change the city name in this request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, request

i'm starting learning JS and i don't understand how to change ( as a user ) the city name on this request .
It's working when in my request i put the city name in askWeather.open("GET", "url.../london)
but how can i give the possibilty to the user to change this value ?

Thanks a lot

```
askWeather.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState = XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let resp = document.getElementById('result');
        let ask = document.getElementById('btn');
        ask.addEventListener('click', function () {
            resp.innerHTML = response.current_condition.condition;
        });
    }
};
askWeather.open("GET", "https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/lille");
askWeather.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an event listener for the value that has been typed and also an event Listener when the request should be sent.

This is one way how you could let the user to change the city:

```js
let city = 'london'; // The default value, if the user didn't try to set a value
document.getElementById('city').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    city = e.target.value;  
});

document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', () => {
    askWeather.open("GET", `url.../${city}`)
    askWeather.send();
});
```

```html
<input id="city" type="text">
<button id="send">Send the request</button>
```

But you could use a simple form as well with only 1 event listener, like:

```js
let city = 'london';
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
  city = document.getElementById('city').value;
  askWeather.open("GET", `url.../${city}`)
  askWeather.send();
});
```

```html
<form id="my-form" action="">
  <input id="city" type="text">
  <input type="submit" id="send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable for the city name, you can set this value from wherever you wish, like from user input.

```js
const city = 'lille';
askWeather.open("GET", `https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/${city}`);
```